# How to make selectable text with 100% height and 100% width of a Grid Cell

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight application and I try to display a generated text into a Cell of my grid. Unfortunately the TextBox does not seem to be able to have a stretching height and stretching width to his parent size. For the moment, I have simply use a ScrollViewer and Set the content but I can't select the text so I still have a problem.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Generate" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Click="GenerateSerialization" />
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrollText" Grid.Column="2"></ScrollViewer>
    <sdk:GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="gridSplitter1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
</Grid>
```

Comment: this.scrollText.Content = "asdasdasd"; The problem with TextBox is that is does not size to the grid size and when the user put the cursor inside the textbox he can see a little textbox inside the scrollviewer.

Comment: Do you mean: TextBox tbx = new TextBox() { Text="asdadad" }; ? By the way... the Grid can resize the textbox.

Comment: However... as your textbox is not direct child of the Grid, the magic is not working.

Comment: I want the TextBox to Fill all the cell size, what ever what's in the textbox.

Comment: <TextBox Grid.Column="2"... but not inside the scrollviewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry... when I think I understand English I see have a lot of road to travel :o)
Check this:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollText"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              Grid.Column="2">
  <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="Bla, bla, bla..." />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: The problem is that I can see the TextBox not taking the whole cell.

Comment: Well.. I took your whole XAML and after the change I mentioned did a run and clearly see the textbox takes the whole cell (sadly can't post an image). Would it be possible to share your project to give a better look?